# Adding Azure AD B2C Into Asp.net Middleware (Entity Framework) for Auth: IDW10106: The 'ClientId' option must be provided

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have set up my program.cs like so:

```
 var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection1");
    
    if (connectionString == null)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("DefaultConnection is not set");
    }
    
    
    
    //builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration);
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<MigrationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
    builder.Services.AddDatasyncControllers();
    
    var app = builder.Build();
    
    // Initialize the database
    using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MigrationDbContext>();
        //await context.InitializeDatabaseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    
    // Configure and run the web service.
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.MapControllers();
    app.Run();
```

and my appsettings like this:

```
{
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://skillbasedauth.b2clogin.com",
    "Domain": "skillbasedauth.onmicrosoft.com",
    "ClientId": "XXX"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=NewDb;Trusted_Connection=True"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

But the app fails to start stating that it couldnt find ClientId which in my eyes is clearly set here.

Anyone got any ideas on what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration section should be name 'AzureAd' as mentioned [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/web-apis).

Edit: There is an overload that allows you specify a different configuration section name, as you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.web.microsoftidentitywebapiauthenticationbuilderextensions.addmicrosoftidentitywebapi?view=msal-model-dotnet-latest).

Comment: thats not correct. for b2c ist deffo called this way.

Comment: The [source code](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/blob/d4662a9b61cd66f152749b7e29758d764bfa83d4/src/Microsoft.Identity.Web/WebApiExtensions/MicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.cs#L44C8-L44C8) of the MicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthenticationBuilderExtensions class shows they're expecting 'AzureAd' by default.